# Is this idiomatic Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I've started doing Project Euler using Clojure, as a first stab at learning Clojure. I've solved the first assignment:

> Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

I've previously solved it in Python:

```
sum(i for i in xrange(1000) if i%3==0 or i%5==0)
```

This is my first Clojure attempt:

```
(reduce +
  (filter 
    (fn [x]
      (or 
        (= 0 (mod x 3)) 
        (= 0 (mod x 5))))
    (range 1000)))
```

I'm actually suprised about how verbose it got, but I'm pretty sure it's because of my style and ignorance of Clojure idioms.

What would an idiomatic version of this Clojure code look like?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is how I did it:

```
(apply +
  (filter #(or (zero? (mod % 3))
               (zero? (mod % 5)))
    (range 1000)))
```

What makes my solution *slightly* more idiomatic is the use of the anonymous function reader macro, `#(...)` and the `zero?` `fn`

Your solution is **different** but just as **good**!

BTW - solving euler problems is a great way to learn a new language - you can't get everything from a book.

**Edit:**

I decided to provide a different solution more inline with your Python version (not very pretty IMO)

```
(apply +
  (for [i (range 1000) :when (or (zero? (mod i 3))
                                 (zero? (mod i 5)))]
    i))
```

Comment: thanks a lot, that cleans it up quite a bit! what would be the advantage here of using apply vs reduce?

Comment: `+` has variable arity so it prevents us from executing `+` multiple times. In reality, it is equivalent to using `reduce` because `+` uses `reduce` once the arg list goes over 2 (see the source for `+`). In this example, it's really just my style more than anything else.

Comment: thanks again, is there some style guide which for example, advocates the way you've aligned the or-arguments?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still learning the "correct" style - this is a good read - https://github.com/bbatsov/clojure-style-guide - you'll notice that I'm not really following it 100%

Comment: @gumuz I added a version more inline with your Python solution - not as clean IMO.

Comment: Variation on a theme: `(apply + (for [i (range 1000) :when (some zero? (map (partial mod i) [3 5]))] i))`

Answer (score 9):

Just another version:

```
(defn sum-of [n]
  (reduce + (range n 1000 n)))

(+ (sum-of 3) (sum-of 5) (- (sum-of 15)))
```

Comment: Cute.  Also `(reduce + (distinct (concat (range 3 1000 3) (range 5 1000 5))))`

Answer (score 0):

I like trying to solve a general solution for things Project Euler, so here's my generic solution:

```
(defn sum-multiples [nums lim]
  (reduce
   +
   (filter
    (fn [x]
      (some identity
            (map #(zero? (mod x %)) nums)))
    (range lim))))
```

and then just call:

```
(sum-multiples [3 5] 1000)
```